# I keep getting short internet outages but my ISP says everything is fine. How should I proceed?

Tags: networking, internet, isp

I have a fibre internet connection as is typical in the UK - normal telephone cable to my house, then a combined home modem/router.

My connection is generally stable and consistent in terms of performance, but least once a day I loose service typically for 30s - 1min, sometimes a little longer but very rarely longer than 2 minutes. I work at home over RDP so I notice immediately, most people probably would not even be aware.

When I ping `google.com` from my Mac I will typically see a response time of 13ms. When the problem occurs I may see timeouts but more typically, the ping will jump to several seconds or several tens of seconds in a brief 'spike'.

I've confirmed that **I can connect to my router (192.168.xxx.xx) interface and it reports the internet connection is down at these times**. My devices connect to my router/modem fine, but it says the connection to the outside world is lost. e.g.
[image]

In my router logs all I see is this (last outage was 14:52):
[image]

Contacting my ISP their reply is:

> I have looked into your account and there is stable connection with no
> drops in last 50 days. Looks like issues you are experiencing are down
> to wireless performance as line up to router is working fine

I am curious what/how their line check could entail so I can respond more usefully? Are they constantly pinging my modem otherwise how would they know if it is connected OK? If they say it's all fine on their side how can I investigate further and what should I be asking them to do?

It seems to me either their line has a problem, or my router is mistakenly reporting a lost connection. But how can I figure out which?

Comment: What master socket do you have? Push for a new faceplate from openreach.

Comment: Did your ISP provide the modem/router? What happens if you ping the router's IP (the private IP your router has in your LAN not the public IP)? Some router interfaces give you the option to send out a ping as a trouble shooting tool, if this is available try to ping google directly from your router. Also make sure to ping different public IPs (use more then one and don't use just the DNS name, but ping the IP directly).

Comment: Could be router trouble, some other machine on your network doing it's daily upload of photos or backups or any number of other things. There is nothing definitive in your question saying this is an isp problem. Your ISP will have access to low level error rates on your phone line (at the physical house to box on the street level) and be able to see when actual disconnects or sync errors occur. A machine on your network suddenly saturating your upstream could cause this kind of problem.

Comment: “I am curious what/how their line check could entail so I can respond more usefully?” We have no idea what their procedure is. So nobody can answer this. But if you are experiencing this with Wi-Fi it could all be due to a localized Wi-Fi issue at your location. What could that be? Who knows. But that is more likely what your issue is. The best way to test this is to have a pure ethernet connection from your modem to your location in your home and see what’s up.

Comment: Heck, even a microwave cooker or baby monitor can cause WiFi problems and drop outs with poor shielding. There was even a news story a couple of weeks ago where an old CRT style TV was actually knocking out the broadband for an entire village every morning because it let out a pulse that upset the signals on the lines. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-54239180

Comment: @Giacomo1968 as I said in my question, the router/modem is reporting the external connection is dropped. I can connect to my router over local intranet just fine.

Comment: @Mr.Boy “I've confirmed that my router reports the internet connection is down at these times, and that both wired/WiFi devices lose connection.” Then if that is the case, contact your ISP and tell them their router is reporting connection issues. Nothing else to add.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I did that - they reiterated "we see no issues for 50 days".

Comment: @Mr.Boy Then push back and ask to escalate the issue. Most likely the person you are communicating with is lower on the customer service chain and honestly is just reading data off of a screen. Go higher up the tech support food chain.

Comment: @Mr.Boy what exactly do you mean by "the external connection is dropped"? How did you confirm that? Please be more specific.

Comment: Does your router have a detailed connection log that you could check? It would have to contain modem status events to be really useful.

Comment: @albin, I mean the router software says the internet isn't connected... exactly as if I pulled the WAN cable out the back, basically

Comment: @Mr.Boy Appearances are deceiving in this case disconnecting the modem entirely or e.g. just disconnecting the PPP session is not the same thing, I would still try to find the exact source, there's still a bit you can do. That being said if you can not do any more troubleshooting, I would just tell tech support that the router itself says that there is no internet connection. If they provided the router that usually does the trick.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really way too broad and is not focused on a single issue that can be solved. The ultimate issue is the client saying one thing and the ISP saying another. The only solution is to contact the ISP and insist there are issues so the issue can be pushed up the tech support chain.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 then it's not broad is it. If that's your answer, post it. My questions were basically 1)how can I try to verify on my side where the problem is 2)what should I do with this.

Comment: Is this DSL or FTTC? Who's the ISP? I don't recognise the router interface page. Go to [DSLReports](http://www.dslreports.com) & set up a line monitor. You need to sign up but you can set up a basic monitor for free. Use this as ammunition in your discussions with your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, your IPS (seems to) monitors the connection between your modem and the endpoint it connects to (it's a little more complicated then a "simple" ping).

Basically the ISP has a stable connection to your modem and assumes the problem is "behind" the modem on your end (your LAN). In my experience this is often the case due to IP conflicts, defective HW etc.

You can do systematic trouble shooting, to check for the problem's source (see comment):

- What happens if you ping the router's IP (the private IP your router has in your LAN not the public IP)?
- Some router interfaces give you the option to send out a ping as a trouble shooting tool, if this is available try to ping google directly from your router.
- Also make sure to ping different public IPs (use more then one and don't use just the DNS name, but ping the IP directly).
- If you router get's a public IP from your ISP (an doesn't block ICMP) you could try to ping your router through a different internet connection (e.g. your mobile phone when you are not connected to the internet)

Alternatively I would check if you can just connect one device via Ethernet through your router and disable the WLAN temp. Or better: disable your router and WLAN functionality and establishing a PPPoE connection directly with your "modem" over a LAN cable (as long as this is supported by your ISP and your modem not all devices support PPPoE). Make sure to use a software firewall if you connect your machine directly via PPPoE.

This can eliminate most things that can go wrong on your side. If the problem still persists it's most likely a problem with the modem/router and you need to replace the device. But some further testing will be necessary to be sure.

If for some reason you can not do any more troubleshooting, to find the cause, I would just tell tech support that the router itself says that there is no internet connection (not your device). If the ISP provided the router that usually does the trick and they will help you in the further steps.

Comment: One problem is that these outages are so short-lived, running tests during them is quite tricky :) [not a comment on the downvote that wasn't me]

Comment: @Mr.Boy I see, if you can not run test, did you try to eliminate sources by connecting just one device to the router or bypassing the router as well by establishing a PPPoE connection?

Comment: @Albin I'm fairly sure that here in the UK I cannot directly to the phone line without a modem for fibre (VDSL)

Comment: @Albin I downvoted because this is a “[Hail Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass)” answer that is an extended comment that attempts to throw every theoretical answer/idea at a question that is too broad and unfocused and honestly not something that can be easily answered past, “Contact your ISP and insist there is an issue and talk to someone higher up the food chain…”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for replying. Although I understand your critic, I don't agree. The reason being is that I gave instructions on the next troubleshooting steps (not hail mary "solution" like updates etc. in which case I would have agreed with your assessment). In my view there should be more specific troubleshooting before contacting tech support especially because it has already been contacted once.  But other then that I agree the question could have had much more specific information. Hope you consider my view as well and feel free to engage in further discussion.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I think you are confusing s.th. either you have VDSL (copper) or fiber, or please explain how you have both (via diagram etc.). You don't establish a PPPoE connections directly through the phone line, you will still be using your "modem". And you don't need to anonymise private IP addresses (in fact it makes it only harder to help you) or your ISP's IP only your public IP (at least if it's static).

Comment: @Albin “Hope you consider my view as well and feel free to engage in further discussion.” There is no more discussion. The original poster has a classic “One person says one thing another person says another thing…” issue and typically at ISPs the first person that one contacts is someone at the lowest rungs who just says what they are told to say. The solution right now is to escalate and perhaps provide the screenshots they have posted here as a reference. Past that, there is nothing anyone here can say/do. This question cannot every be clearly answered by anyone here.

Comment: @albin in the UK Fibre to cabinet, then copper to the house, is sold as Fibre broadband.